# Azure Session Consumer seems to be locked to same Worker Service even when Message gets Abandoned

Tags: azure, session, azureservicebus

I have an Azure Message Bus Topic.
I have one "Session enabled" Azure Message Bus Consumer for this Topic.
I have around 3 Worker Services that are using the same Consumer. So the work is shared between these 3 Workers.
The Messages which are sent to the consumer need to be ordered, thats why I am using the "Session Feature" on the Consumer.

I believe that on a first Message, the Session of the Message gets bind to a Worker Service.
For certain Reasons I want to abandon not only a Message but also the session so that it can be picked up by another of the 3 Worker Services.

My questions:

1. Is this possible?
2. If yes how can I do this in the code?
3. Is there something like "Accept Session Or Not" Handler which kicks in when Message received?

See code below:

```
        private void SetupServiceBusSessionProcessors2()
        {
            var busProcessorOptions = new ServiceBusSessionProcessorOptions();

            var busProcessor = _busClient.CreateSessionProcessor("fooTopic", "fooSubscription", busProcessorOptions);

            busProcessor.ProcessMessageAsync += args => ProcessSessionMessageHandler2(args);
        }
        
        private async Task ProcessSessionMessageHandler2(ProcessSessionMessageEventArgs args)
        {
            if (false) // Condition here which Abandons Message AND Session
            {
                // the following line of code seems only to abandon the Message
                // but it seems like the session is locked to this service
                // i want that other services which are listening via the same consumer can try to handle the session
                await args.AbandonMessageAsync(args.Message);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is possible in version [7.3.0-beta.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/7.3.0-beta.1) using the ReleaseSession method on the event args. Note that this is a beta version so the API is subject to change before there is a stable release.